# Over() function does not cover all rows in the table

Tags: mysql, sql, count, where-clause, window-functions

i am practising SQL with MySQL and encounter a strange behaviour in SQL. Say i have a table like this:

```
Delivery table:
+-------------+-------------+------------+-----------------------------+
| delivery_id | customer_id | order_date | customer_pref_delivery_date |
+-------------+-------------+------------+-----------------------------+
| 1           | 1           | 2019-08-01 | 2019-08-02                  |
| 2           | 5           | 2019-08-02 | 2019-08-02                  |
| 3           | 1           | 2019-08-11 | 2019-08-11                  |
| 4           | 3           | 2019-08-24 | 2019-08-26                  |
| 5           | 4           | 2019-08-21 | 2019-08-22                  |
| 6           | 2           | 2019-08-11 | 2019-08-13                  |
+-------------+-------------+------------+-----------------------------+
```

My query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as imm, count(*) over() as all_t 
FROM 
Delivery
WHERE order_date = customer_pref_delivery_date
```

Result :

```
+-----+-------+
| imm | all_t |
+-----+-------+
| 2   | 1     |
+-----+-------+
```

I expect the **over()** function will cover the whole table, and in this case return 6, but it only returns 1, for some reason. Is there an explanation for this behaviour?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The window function:

```
count(*) over() as all_t
```

operates on the results of the query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as imm  
FROM Delivery
WHERE order_date = customer_pref_delivery_date
```

which is only 1 row (with 1 column) and this is why you get 1 as result.

I believe what you are looking for is conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT COUNT(CASE WHEN order_date = customer_pref_delivery_date THEN 1 END) AS imm, 
       COUNT(*) AS all_t -- here it's the aggregate function COUNT()
FROM Delivery;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=a4974051a42153443307a47d0d145213).

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=fb1ac46b3f0be22be8731ce96b91c291 ?

Comment: @VBoka thanks, I used the fiddle in my demo.

Comment: so the explanation is the WHERE clause limits the number of rows that my over() function will cover ?

Comment: Hi @forpas but my link is a question that asks you how did I got this 3 results in this 3 query's in my demo ?

Comment: @AnhTuấnPhạm No. Even if you remove the WHERE clause, the result will still be 1 for all_t: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=80856d1525506a2fbcefd61dac4ebdc2

Comment: @AnhTuấnPhạm the window function is executed after the SELECT statement is executed (although it is inside the SELECT statement) and returns the aggregate COUNT(*). So it operates on this result which is 1 row.

Comment: @VBoka https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=d3083f0952d6f833f35c364ce7a5ed40

Answer (score 2):

The `SELECT COUNT(*)` counts rows that satisfy the conditions in the WHERE clause. There are two such rows.

The query with an aggregate function but no GROUP BY returns a single row, to report the count. The window function then applies to that result set, and counts 1 row. In other words, window functions apply to the set of rows *after* aggregation has reduced the number of rows.

You can test this by omitting the aggregation:

```
mysql> SELECT count(*) over() as all_t  FROM  Delivery WHERE order_date = customer_pref_delivery_date;
+-------+
| all_t |
+-------+
|     2 |
|     2 |
+-------+
```

Or without the conditions of the WHERE clause, it returns the count of rows for each of the set of six rows:

```
mysql> SELECT count(*) over() as all_t  FROM  Delivery;
+-------+
| all_t |
+-------+
|     6 |
|     6 |
|     6 |
|     6 |
|     6 |
|     6 |
+-------+
```