# Over() function does not cover all rows as expected

Tags: mysql, group-by, average, window-functions

I have been practising SQL, and came across this behaviour i couldnt explain. ( I am also the one who asked this question : [Over() function does not cover all rows in the table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71944312/over-function-does-not-cover-all-rows-in-the-table)) -> its a different problem.

Suppose i have a table like this

### MovieRating table:

| movie_id | user_id | rating | created_at |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 3 | 2020-01-12 |
| 1 | 2 | 4 | 2020-02-11 |
| 1 | 3 | 2 | 2020-02-12 |
| 1 | 4 | 1 | 2020-01-01 |
| 2 | 1 | 5 | 2020-02-17 |
| 2 | 2 | 2 | 2020-02-01 |
| 2 | 3 | 2 | 2020-03-01 |
| 3 | 1 | 3 | 2020-02-22 |
| 3 | 2 | 4 | 2020-02-25 |

What I am trying to do, is to rank the movie by rating, which i have this SQL query:

```sql
SELECT
  movie_id,
  rank() over(partition by movie_id order by avg(rating) desc) as rank_rate
FROM
  MovieRating
```

From my previous question, i learnt that the **over()** function will operate in a window selected by the query, basically the window this query returns:

```sql
SELECT movie_id FROM MovieRating
```

So I would expect to see at least 3 rows here, for id 1, 2 and 3.

The result is however just one row:

```json
{"headers": ["movie_id", "rank_rate"], "values": [[1, 1]]}
```

Why is that ? Is something wrong with my understanding regarding how `over()` function works ?

Comment: That shouldn't even normally run. You have an aggregate function *(`AVG(rating)`)* which only makes sense with a `GROUP BY`; implicitly you're saying group everything to a single row...   Yet, you also have `movie_id`, which is neither in a `GROUP BY` nor an aggregate function. This implies you've disabled `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` to get this to run. Don't do that. Re-enable that mode, and wrote a correct query *(by adding `GROUP BY movie_id`)*

Comment: Perhaps comparing these queries will help you unpick your misunderstandings? https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=148abb6d41335507c1bb32797bc09ff3 (Just bear in mind three things; having any aggregate functions implicitly means your query is aggregating the source data, aggregation without a group by clause then means you're aggregating everything to a single result row, and the aggregation is always done before the window functions)

Comment: @MatBailie ahhhh i guess i understand it now, so the problem was the avg() function turns my whole window into one row, and therefore whatever i got for "movie_id" is just the first value of the table.

Thanks!

Comment: It doesn't change the 'window'. It changes the source data that the function operates on. You're effectively doing `SELECT movie_id, AVG(rating) FROM table` *(which would normally error, but is currently giving you one output row)* and ***then*** running the window function on the result of that.

Comment: Perhaps these will help? https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=0594df12f0864e8d61a3023c56b68228 (I'm slow, as I'm on my phone on a train.)

Comment: @MatBailie i think i still have one question left, if i have group by, the window will become a list of groups, and then my "avg" function will work on that list of groups, and the "partition by" clause will split the rank function into another list of groups, and hence each movie_id will have rank 1. Is that correct ?
I added what i meant in your latest fiddle.

Comment: When you edit a fiddle, a new dbfiddle and link are generated (so, I can't see your edits). Please post the new link here. (I'm getting off my train now, I can answer again in half an hour or so.) But, the simple answer is to rewrite your queries with the aggregation in a sub query first (like in my most recent fiddle), and then you'll see that the output of the aggregation is the input to the window functions (by that point, what the underlying tables looked like is irrelevant).

Comment: @MatBailie this one :D https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=548a190de49918843084558809256b66

Comment: The last query is exactly the same as mine two queries above it, which is Functionally identical to the one two above that.  You're aggregating down to three rows, then applying a window function over those three rows. Your partition is on movie, which means that all rows with the same movie id are considered separately from all other rows (a new sequence is started for each movie). As there is only one row per movie (as the aggregation has already happened) all rows get ranked as 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need an aggregation query and use `RANK()` window function on its results:

```
SELECT movie_id,
       AVG(rating) AS average_rating, -- you may remove this line if you don't actually need the average rating
       RANK() OVER (ORDER BY AVG(rating) DESC) AS rank_rate
FROM MovieRating
GROUP BY movie_id
ORDER BY rank_rate;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=68aae451232fb3a5edfd51938a9551b9).

Your query is an aggregation query without a `group by` clause and this means that it operates on the whole table and not to each `movie_id`. Such queries return only 1 row with the result of the aggregation.
When yo apply `RANK()` window function, it will operate on that single row and not on the table.

Comment: I understand that using group by will get me what i want, but what is the reason why i need it ? Why my window function does not cover all the rows in the table ?

Comment: @AnhTuấnPhạm your query does not even run: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=234f5c03df7210bae52d083bdcff9f83 Are you sure that you are using MySql?

Comment: @AnhTuấnPhạm It ***does*** cover all rows. But by including an aggregate function you're telling the database that you want to aggregate the data, and by not having a `GROUP BY` you're saying that you want to aggregate the whole table to one row. That aggregation is done ***before*** the window function is applied.  As written it only even runs if you disable `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY`, which you should ***not*** do.  You're effectively using `ANY_VALUE()` without knowing it; https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=e914797bc59a94bd330f6048f3d7dc61 Just re-enable `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY`...

Comment: @AnhTuấnPhạm maybe you are using MariaDB (or SQLite ?). This is the result of your query without the window function: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=234f5c03df7210bae52d083bdcff9f83 It returns 1 row with an arbitrary movie_id and the average of all ratings of all movies. If you apply then RANK it will operate on that single row.

Comment: @forpas i am practising in leetcode, and it says MySQL

Comment: @AnhTuấnPhạm then probably ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY is disabled and this allows you to execute queries like the query in your question which does not make sense because as I explained in my previous comment, returns only 1 row because it is an aggregation query operating on the whole table and not to each movie_id (for this you would need `group by movie_id`).

Comment: @forpas so i guess my misunderstanding is the part where the window function only works on group, and if i dont have group by it will consider my whole table as one big group.

it does however not check out for me in the case i use LAG or LEAD, which for me are also windows functions, but they do not need group by to work as expected.

Comment: @AnhTuấnPhạm the window function operates on the results of the query. If the query uses aggregate functions like SUM(), AVG(), MAX() etc (without a group by clause) it will return 1 row only. Then any window function, including LAG or LEAD, will operate on that single row.

Comment: @AnhTuấnPhạm No, you do not ever ***require*** aggregation (or group by) for window functions to work. It's just that window functions are applied ***after*** aggregation, and that your use of AVG() without a group by tells the database you're aggregating the whole table down to a single result row (again, ***before*** the window function does its work).

Answer (score 2):

I think you mean to get one row for each movie, with its average rating.

You should use `GROUP BY`, not a window function:

```
SELECT movie_id, AVG(rating) AS avg_rating
FROM MovieRating
GROUP BY movie_id
ORDER BY avg_rating DESC;
```

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/o9qLFbJEwhaHDWoTS9Qfwp/1

---

The reason you only got one row is that when you use an aggregate function like `AVG()`, that implicitly makes the query into an aggregating query. The result of the query is one row per group.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/aggregate-functions.html says:

> If you use an aggregate function in a statement containing no GROUP BY clause, it is equivalent to grouping on all rows.

In other words, the whole table is considered one "group" if you use `AVG()` but don't specify a `GROUP BY` expression. Because the whole table is a single group, the result is one row.

Windows defined by windowing functions are not the same as groups defined by aggregate functions. The window functions are applied after the rows have been reduced by aggregation. Since there was only one group and therefore one row in your result, the rank was 1.

Comment: I understand that using group by will get me what i want, but what is the reason why i need it ? Why my window function does not cover all the rows in the table ?